# In MSVC cannot view the source code of external libraries but have source code

Tags: c, debugging, intellisense, visual-studio-2010

I'm running visual studio 2010 (ultimate), for C development.

I have a C library with pre-compiled dll's but I have the pdb and the source code.

However, when I right-click on a method to 'view definition' it just takes me to the header file and not the source. The same happens when debugging.

In visual studio I've added the folder with the source code to the 'source folder' configuration and I've also tried storing the pdb with the dll and the lib files.

Do I need to do anything else?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried compiling the library on your system, with your compiling options?

Comment: No, that would probably work, I just want to get it working without having to compile the system as there are loads of dependencies and compiling takes a long time. I just don't understand what MSVC requires when you try and view the source code via intellisense (or debugging)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio C/C++ source navigation is pathetic, and pretty much always has been.  Personally I wouldn't waste valuable time trying to bend it to my desires.

VisualAssist (www.wholetomato.com) is a great 3rd party add-in, which IMO everybody using VS for C/C++ development should invest in.  It has a 'goto' feature, which Just Works.

No interest to declare, just a long-term (distressingly so!) satisfied customer.

Comment: I've used VA in the past but I don't have a licence now. I would just like to understand what MSVC requires when you try and view the source code via intellisense (or debugging)

Comment: It probably requires something involving the sacrifice of goats.